# Print dynamic information to the console

Tags: python, windows-console

I have a small console program, and it's necessary to print several lines of information, which is dynamically updated while running the application. While there was not much data to print, it fitted in one line and I used just `'\r'`, but how to deal with multiple lines?

What is the best (simplest? general?) method to do this?

Comment: I always just re-print the info to the screen with a bunch of `\n` proceeding.  Each iteration pushes the last one up and off the screen buffer.  On linux at least, (38400 baud vt100 terminal) its fast enough you don't notice it- I imagine Windows would be similar.

Comment: @tMC: doesn't that require you to detect the size of the terminal, which itself is tricky to do in a cross-platform way?

Comment: really I think the only way to do what you want is to use the curses library...
(assuming you want to have a screen that updates in place and doesnt just scroll the next stats up)

Comment: @tMC: while it's possible, there must be another, more _accurate_ method, 'cause there are programs that do this kind of thing.

Comment: @Wooble what terminal is 1000 lines tall? `print \n*1000`

Comment: @chersanya in linux we have ncurses that could do it- idk if such a thing exists in windows.

Comment: yes there is curses for windows as well .. and a python library that is multiplatform

Comment: @JoranBeasley: yes, curses is a way, and if there are no simpler alternatives I'll use it. However, I've found some codes for terminal that move line up for example, but they don't seem to work in Windows.

Comment: Do an `os.system('cls')` between each set of lines?

Comment: actually cdarke's solution may work ... but the only reliable way Ive done this is with curses...(but I think cdarke's solution should work for this...)

Comment: @cdarke: `cls` for Windows and `clear` for other, will both work (for portability)?

Comment: `print '\33[H\33[2J',` is better than creating a subprocess to run `clear` in linux.

Comment: @tMC: oh, what's official name for such character sequences? I've seen them several times, but don't know how they are called.

Comment: ANSI Escape Codes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code The windows terminal may recognize them as well? All the `clear` command on linux does is echo that code; hence why I prefer to do it in my own code if applicable.

Comment: @tMC: no, windows console doesn't support them at all, however it is still interesting :) (I use linux too)

Comment: ANSI is how you create colored, bold, underlined etc text on the linux terminal. (those that support it; I don't believe a true vt100 terminal supports ANSI)

Answer (score 0):

You can print the informations on a file

```
myFile = open('nameFile','w')
myFile.write(data1)
... 
myFile.write(data2)
myFile.write('\n')
```

and flush when you need:

```
myFile.flush()
```

you get a new line by writing '\n'.

You can also flush the standard output if you keep writing on it:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

when you need it and you get a newline with '\n' or by omitting the comma at the end of each print.